# I implemented Serializable but it still give me exception

Tags: java

this is my code:
i dont know where is the error
I search every where but I didn't get the answer
so any one of you guys have the answer for my question?
because I'm new to files, and i want to complete this project

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class eManager implements Serializable {
  
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  private long copyId;
  private int event;
  private int totalT;


  public eManager(long copyId) {
    this.copyId = copyId;
  }

  public void Calc(int eventss) {
    int teckits = 10;
    this.event = eventss;
    int events = eventss;

    if (events % 10 > 4)
      teckits++;
    teckits += (events - 10) / 10;

    totalT = teckits * events;
  }

  public long getCopyId() {
    return copyId;
  }

  public int getTotalT() {
    return totalT;
  }

  public void data() {
    System.out.println("**<@" + copyId + "> --> " + totalT + "**");
  }

  public void data2() {
    System.out.println("**<@" + copyId + "> --> " + event + "**");

  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? What's the exception you're getting? ...

Comment: Everything field inside a `Serializable` has to either be null, or be refer to an instance of a `Serializable` class (and that instance's fields have to be null or Serializable too). A `Scanner` isn't `Serializable`, so you can't serialize an instance of this class. You don't even seem to use `s`, so just remove it?

Comment: First of all: what's the error and when? Second the Scanner isn't be  used anyhow. Therefore why use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything field inside a `Serializable` has to either be null, or be refer to an instance of a `Serializable` class (and that instance's fields have to be null or Serializable too).

A `Scanner` isn't `Serializable` because that would need to transitively serialize the stream it is reading from, and it can't do that, for example if it's reading from the input stream of the process or a network connection, so you can't serialize an instance of this class.

You don't even seem to use `s`, so just remove it?